# How to hide the command when using command repetition with the exclamation mark?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

When I use ! to execute a previous command it automatically prints the command as well. Is there a way to hide this?

Example:
This is what happens:

```
ralgrad:~$ echo test
test
ralgrad:~$ !!
echo test
test
```

This is what I would want:

```
ralgrad:~$ echo test
test
ralgrad:~$ !!
test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the bash source and there is no way to disable this automatic printing of the expanded command. You would have to compile your own version of bash!

If it is particularly important to you for whatever reason, look in `bashhist.c` in the `pre_process_line` function and comment out/remove the following line:

```
printf (stderr, "%s\n", history_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just found this function recently and when using it, it bugged me that it made that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `!!`, because it repeats *the last command* not *the last output*. As far as I know, there is no single command that allows to achieve what you are asking. However, you can try a simple hack:

```
result=`echo test`
echo "$result"
```

Comment: He's asking for `!!` to not output the expanded command before running it (i.e. the opposite of !!:p).

Comment: I know, and my solution does what exactly what he wants: command gets executed only once, and you can repeat output of it as many times as you want.

Comment: He wants to execute the command multiple times (using wildcard expansion) without the expanded command being printed. That is not what your solution does.

Comment: I don't see anything about *multiple times* in the question. This script would reproduce output in the example.

Comment: Fair enough, this is an XY problem (we don't know what problem the OP is trying to solve) so your answer could well do the job.

Comment: Exactly, the question itself is not clear enough to provide a single answer. Need to know more about the context, i.e. what is the goal of all this.

Comment: It was mainly something that was bugging me when using !! or aything alike. I don't want the last output though. I do want to repeat the last command.

Comment: Then use `result="echo test"` - it will repeat command and print the output every time you use `result`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simulate what you want with the following batch file:

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
exe=`fc -lrn | awk 'NR==2 {print;}'`
else
exe=`fc -lrn | cut -f2- | awk 'NR>=2 {print;}' | grep "^ $*" | head -n1 `
fi
eval $exe
```

Let `h` be the name of the file (or, if you want it, even `!`). Then you can do:

```
# echo Foo
Foo
# echo Bar
Bar
# h 
Bar
# h echo F
Foo
```